# cross compiling settings (clfs)

Tags: kernel, cross-compiling, clfs

I am following the cross compile book, in section 4.6 (http://clfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/arm/cross-tools/binutils.html). I have done the preparation of binutils, and the 
make configure-host
But after this, when I do the make.
I have the following error, i cant manage to understand:

```
{https://pastebin.com/UB2v5vVt}
```

`/mnt/clfs/sources/binutils-build/binutils-2.28/missing: 81: /mnt/clfs/sources/binutils-build/binutils-2.28/missing: makeinfo: not found
WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or
         any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.
         You might want to install the Texinfo package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/>
         The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of
         using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might
         want to install GNU make:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/make/>
Makefile:472: recipe for target 'bfd.info' failed
make[3]: *** [bfd.info] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/clfs/sources/binutils-build/binutils-2.28/bfd/doc'`

I read that the Warning could be ignored, and still make it work, so I dont think there is the error.
Thanks a lot.
Cactus.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that `makeinfo` is not installed on your host system. You don't describe what your host system is, so I can't suggest how to install it (possibly `apt` or `yum`), other than by downloading the latest `texinfo` from the FSF and building it from scratch.

But the error can safely be ignored. You don't need the documentation installed for your cross tools anyway.